# Moment obtendo o valor do mês anterior, mesmo depois de somar um mês

Tags: javascript, data, momentjs

Estou tentando trabalhar com o **Moment.js**

```
var data = moment("2019-08-17", "YYYY-M-D").add('months', 1);

alert(data);

dia = data.date();
mes = data.month();
ano = data.year();
```

O `alert(data)` me dá a data correta mas quando separo `mes = data.month()`, me retorna o mês corrente e não o calculado!

Onde estou errando?

Comment: A sintaxe está errada, altere a ordem `.add(1, 'month')`

Comment: obrigado! De fato, ela era assim mas mudou recentemente! Ví na documentação!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vamos por partes:

---

#### Ordem dos parâmetros no método `add`

Não sei qual versão do [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com) você está usando, mas a [documentação do método `add`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/add/) diz o seguinte:

> *Before version **2.8.0**, the `moment#add(String, Number)` syntax was also supported. It has been deprecated in favor of `moment#add(Number, String)`.*

Em tradução livre:

> Antes da versão **2.8.0**, a sintaxe `moment#add(String, Number)` também era suportada, mas esta foi depreciada em favor de `moment#add(Number, String).`

Ou seja, `add('months', 1)` também vai funcionar, mas ao usar a versão mais atual do Moment.js, eu obtive uma mensagem informando o que a documentação indica:

> *Deprecation warning: moment().add(period, number) is deprecated. Please use moment().add(number, period). See http://momentjs.com/guides/#/warnings/add-inverted-param/ for more info.*

Obs: usei a versão **2.24.0**. Para ver qual você está usando, basta fazer `console.log(moment.version)`.

De qualquer forma, `add('months', 1)` funciona. Mas por estar *deprecated*, sugiro mudar para a sintaxe nova (`add(1, 'months')`), caso esteja usando uma versão >= 2.8.0.

---

#### Valor numérico do mês

Se olharmos a documentação do [método `month`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/month/), veremos que o valor retornado está entre 0 e 11, pois os meses são indexados em zero (janeiro é zero, fevereiro é 1, etc). *Provavelmente* foi feito assim para manter a compatibilidade com o [`Date` nativo do JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth), que [possui este mesmo comportamento](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/405994/112052).

Ou seja, bastaria somar 1 para obter o valor numérico correto (janeiro igual a 1, fevereiro igual a 2, etc):

```js
// usar a sintaxe nova: add(numero, string)
let data = moment("2019-08-17", "YYYY-M-D").add(1, 'months');

console.log(data);

let mes = data.month() + 1; // somar 1 pois janeiro é zero, fevereiro é 1, etc
console.log(mes); // 9
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Apenas um ponto de atenção: apesar dos meses serem indexados em zero, o [construtor que recebe duas strings (uma com a data e outra com o formato)](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) considera os valores corretos do mês. Por isso `moment("2019-08-17", "YYYY-M-D")` cria uma data em agosto. Mas ao obter o valor numérico no método `month`, aí é usada a regra de janeiro ser zero. Confuso, mas é assim que foi feito.

---

Outra opção para obter o valor do mês é usar [`format`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/), que não usa a regra de "janeiro é zero":

```js
// usar a sintaxe nova: add(numero, string)
let data = moment("2019-08-17", "YYYY-M-D").add(1, 'months');

console.log(data);

console.log(data.format('M')); // 9

// com o zero antes, caso o mês seja menor que 10
console.log(data.format('MM')); // 09
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
```

A diferença é que `month()` retorna um número, enquanto `format` retorna uma string. Dependendo do que você vai fazer com este valor, pode fazer diferença.

---

Quanto ao [seu comentário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/403998/moment-obtendo-o-valor-do-m%C3%AAs-anterior-mesmo-depois-de-somar-um-m%C3%AAs/404063?noredirect=1#comment792137_404063), sobre colocar o valor em um `input date`, a [documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input/date) diz que, para setar uma data a este `input`, o valor deve estar no formato [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) ("yyyy-mm-dd"). Isso pode ser obtido usando `format`. Ex:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
    let data = moment("2019-08-17", "YYYY-M-D").add(1, 'months');
    document.querySelector('#mesQueVem').value = data.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <div>
    <input type="date" id="mesQueVem" name="mesQueVem">
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: até aí fui bem mas acontece que eu pego o retorno do moment já incrementado o número de dias e quero jogá-lo em um input type date. Sabe se possível? E como? Se não for possível, como me livrar o problema de que ao fazer mes = data.month();, a variável mes e dia recebe, para valores menores que 10, seu valor sem o 0 na frente e então tenho problema ao enviar esses dados para o input.

Comment: @CarlosRocha Sobre o `input date` e o valor com zero na frente, coloquei um exemplo de cada. Mas se não for isso o que precisa, peço que por favor edite a pergunta com mais detalhes.

Comment: Isso pode estar ocorrendo porque você colocou o formato da data como ```'YYYY-M-D'``` altera o formato para ``` 'YYYY-MM-DD'````

Comment: @RobsonSilva No *parsing* isso não faz diferença, [veja](https://jsfiddle.net/rqm5uv9t/). Faria diferença se "YYYY-M-D" fosse usado no `format`.

Comment: @hkotsubo, é verdade, então tente acrescentar o ```.format('YYYY-MM-DD)``` ao final, e os valores recupardos estarão com os com os 0 na frente das datas que se fazem necessários.  ```var data = moment("2019-08-17", "YYYY-M-D").add('months', 1).format('YYYY-MM-DD);```

Comment: @RobsonSilva Mas no último exemplo de código eu já faço isso...

Comment: @hkotsubo, então é isso mesmo, creio que será a melhor saída.