# Typescript - Saída do código incorreta - Date

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, data

Por que a saída desse código é:

```
Pessoa {
  Id: 1,
  Name: 'Maicon Gabriel Friedel',
  DateOfBirth: 1997-02-22T03:00:00.000Z
}
```

Código:

```
import pessoa from './pessoa'

pessoa.Id = 1;
pessoa.Name = 'Maicon Gabriel Friedel'
pessoa.DateOfBirth = new Date(1997, 1, 22)

console.log(pessoa);
console.log(pessoa.DateOfBirth.getMonth())
```

Classe `Pessoa`:

```
class Pessoa {
    Id: Number
    Name: String
    DateOfBirth: Date
}

export default new Pessoa()
```

Eu coloquei o mês 1, mas na saída sai 2, o que acontece?

O script que executo é `tsc && node dist/index.js`

E no `getMonth()` ele retorna 1.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

É meio confuso, mas segundo a [documentação de `Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Individual_date_and_time_component_values), o valor numérico do mês é indexado em zero. Ou seja, janeiro é zero, fevereiro é 1, etc.

Portanto, `new Date(1997, 1, 22)` cria uma data referente a **22 de fevereiro de 1997**. O método [`getMonth()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth) também usa esta mesma regra, portanto nesse caso ele retornará `1` (que corresponde a fevereiro).

Mas quando a data é impressa via `console.log`, ela é convertida para algum formato (no caso, o formato foi "1997-02-22T03:00:00.000Z"), e aí o mês assume o valor correto (janeiro é 1, fevereiro é 2, etc).

```js
let d = new Date(1997, 1, 22);
console.log(d); // 1997-02-22T03:00:00.000Z
console.log(d.getMonth()); // 1
```

---

Ou seja, dependendo da situação, você tem que se atentar para usar os valores indexados em zero ou em 1.

No construtor de `Date` (quando este recebe valores numéricos) e no retorno de `getMonth()` (e também no valor passado para o método [`setMonth`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setMonth)), os valores são indexados em zero.

Já os métodos que formatam a data usam o valor correto (indexado em 1):

```js
let d = new Date(1997, 1, 22);
console.log(d.getMonth()); // 1
console.log(d.toISOString()); // 1997-02-22T03:00:00.000Z
console.log(d.toLocaleDateString('pt-BR')); // 22/02/1997

// mudando o mês para dezembro
d.setMonth(11);
console.log(d.toISOString()); // 1997-12-22T02:00:00.000Z
console.log(d.toLocaleDateString('pt-BR')); // 22/12/1997
```

---

Outro ponto que pode confundir mais um pouco é que, quando você passa uma **string** no [formato ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) para o construtor, aí os meses devem ter os valores corretos:

```js
// passando uma string no formato ISO 8601, fevereiro deve ser mês 2
let d = new Date('1997-02-22');
console.log(d.getMonth()); // 1
console.log(d.toISOString()); // 1997-02-22T00:00:00.000Z
console.log(d.toLocaleDateString('pt-BR')); // 21/02/1997
```

Mas repare que nesse caso houve uma diferença: o horário é meia-noite em UTC (o "Z" no final [indica que está em UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Coordinated_Universal_Time_(UTC))), e [`toLocaleDateString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString) retornou dia 21, pois este método usa o timezone do browser (que no meu caso está no Horário de Brasília), e como dia 22 à meia-noite em UTC é igual a dia 21 às 21h do Horário de Brasília, ocorre esta discrepância.

Já quando você usa os valores numéricos (`new Date(1997, 1, 22)`), o `Date` criado corresponde à meia-noite no timezone do browser (no caso, meia-noite no horário de Brasília, que equivale às 3 da manhã em UTC - por isso no primeiro caso o horário é impresso como "03:00:00.000Z"). Esse comportamento é explicado em mais detalhes [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/367167/112052).

---

Só para deixar "mais legal" ainda, o construtor de `Date` não reclama se você passar um mês maior que 11:

```js
let d = new Date(1997, 12, 22);
console.log(d); // 1998-01-22T02:00:00.000Z
console.log(d.getMonth()); // 0
```

Pois é, se passar o mês 12, ele cria uma data referente à janeiro do ano seguinte.

Comment: Meu deus, que loucura hahaahah!! Muito boa sua explicação! Muito obrigado!! Agora entendi essa loucura.. JavaScript e seus poréns malucos :S

Comment: @Maikeaerosmith E olha que datas nem são a coisa mais maluca do JavaScript, tem coisas piores: https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/talks/wat

Answer (score 5):

TL;DR: Não há nada de errado e o código funciona perfeitamente. Aliás, o "*problema*" se deve ao comportamento do JavaScript ao tratar uma data.

---

Se você mexer um pouco com o objeto de datas do JavaScript, [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date), uma hora ou outra trabalhará com meses e fazer algo assim:

```js
console.log(new Date().getMonth());
```

Note que, mesmo estando, por exemplo, em Agosto (mês 08 no nosso calendário), a saída é 7. Isso acontece porque no JavaScript, os meses (e mais algumas informações, como os dias da semana) são trabalhados com índice zero, o que significa que:

- Janeiro ⇒ `0`;
- Fevereiro ⇒ `1`;
- Março ⇒ `2`;
- *E por ai vai...*

Por isso que, ao passar `1` no construtor da data, você está dizendo ao JavaScript que o mês é **fevereiro**, já que, como funcionam com índice zero, janeiro seria `0`.

Para saber mais, leia a documentação relativa ao [`getMonth`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth) e ao [`getDay`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay), que possui um comportamento semelhante.