# Transformar hora em número

Tags: javascript, data

Estou com esse problema: consigo pegar o horário corretamente e mostrar tudo normal, mas quando eu tento transformar a hora em número, ele me retorna `NaN`:

```
var hora = new Date()

var horaAtual = hora.getHours()

var nHoraAtual = Number(horaAtual.value)

var minuto = new Date()

var minutoAtual = minuto.getMinutes()

var nMinutoAtual = Number(minutoAtual.value)

var segundo = new Date()

var nSegundoAtual = Number(nMinutoAtual.value)
```

Comment: Por que `horaAtual.value` e não apenas `horaAtual`?

Comment: Pelo o que eu sei esse .value é uma forma de transformar o número com valor

Comment: Mano, quando você entra com `.getHours()` já vem em número. Imprima o tipo com `typeof horaAtual` e verá no console o resultado `"number"`.

Comment: O retorno de [`Date.prototype.getHours`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getHours) já será um inteiro entre 0 e 23, inclusive. Não é necessário convertê-lo para `Number`.

Comment: Isto vale para as demais funções: `getMinutes()`, `getSeconds()`, etc.

Comment: Só para mostrar como pegar cada item:
`regraData: any  = new Date();
  regraDia: any = new Date().getDate();
  regraMes: any = new Date().getMonth() + 1;
  regraHora: any  = new Date().getHours();
  regraMinuto: any  = new Date().getMinutes();`

O mês tem que somar "+1" porque... nao sei porque, mas pra vir a data certa faço assim.

Comment: Ah sim, entendi Anderson Carlos Woss! Converter a horaAtual para Number estava dando esse problema, agora eu retirei e deu certo! Obrigado

Comment: Outra coisa, não precisa criar `new Date()` toda hora. Vc pode criar `regraData = new Date()` no início e depois só usar `regraData.getDate()`, `regraData.getHours()`, etc

Answer (score 1):

Esses comandos vão pegar o valor que tu quer:

```js
  var regraData = new Date();
  var regraDia = new Date().getDate();
  var regraMes = new Date().getMonth() + 1;
  var regraHora = new Date().getHours();
  var regraMinuto = new Date().getMinutes();
  var regraSegundo = new Date().getSeconds();
```

O mês tem "+1" porque a contagem do mês começa no "0".

EDIT: Conforme explicado pelo @hkotsubo, o melhor é colocar a data em uma variável e chamar essa variável para setar as outras informações:

```js
  var regraData = new Date();
  var regraDia = regraData.getDate();
  var regraMes = regraData.getMonth() + 1;
  var regraHora = regraData.getHours();
  var regraMinuto = regraData.getMinutes();
  var regraSegundo = regraData.getSeconds();
```

Answer (score 1):

Todos os métodos `getXXX` de um [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) já retornam números (veja a [documentação de `getHours()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getHours#Return_value), por exemplo), então não precisa usar `Number`, `value` nem qualquer outro artifício para converter para número, porque ao chamar esses métodos, você já terá um número.

Outro detalhe é que você não precisa ficar toda hora criando `new Date()`, basta criar uma vez só no início e usá-lo para obter os demais valores:

```js
let data = new Date();
let dia = data.getDate();
let mes = data.getMonth() + 1;
let ano = data.getFullYear();
let hora = data.getHours();
let minuto = data.getMinutes();
let segundo = data.getSeconds();
let millis = data.getMilliseconds();

console.log(`ano=${ano}, mês=${mes}, dia=${dia}, hora=${hora}, minuto=${minuto}, segundo=${segundo}, milissegundos=${millis}`);
```

Claro que se usar `new Date()` várias vezes também funciona na maioria dos casos. Mas lembre-se que cada vez que você cria uma nova instância, ela possuirá a data e hora atual do instante em que foi criada.

Dependendo de como o código rodar, pode dar resultados diferentes: a primeira e última execução poderão ter diferença de alguns milissegundos, ou até mesmo de segundos. E se o código rodar muito próximo da meia-noite, até mesmo o dia será diferente.

Ou seja, vamos supor que o código começou a rodar dia 25/09/2019, às 23:59:59.999 - então esta linha obtém o valor `25`:

```
let dia = new Date().getDate();
```

Aí, 1 milésimo de segundo depois, o código chegou na linha que pega o horário:

```
let hora = new Date().getHours();
```

Como já se passou 1 milissegundo, `new Date()` retorna uma data referente a 26/09/2019 à meia-noite, e por isso `hora` tem o valor zero. Então o seu programa mostraria que é meia-noite (hora zero) do dia 25 (que é o valor da variável dia).

Sim, é um *corner case*, "pode ser" que não aconteça "nunca", mas se criar uma nova instância de `Date` toda hora, existe a possibilidade de acontecer. Se quer mostrar todos os dados referentes à mesma data, é melhor criar apenas uma no começo e usar todos *getters* dela, sem criar uma nova desnecessariamente. Ou use [algum outro método de formatação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=javascript%20formatar%20data).

Quanto ao valor do mês, tive que somar 1 porque em JavaScript [os meses são indexados em zero](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/405994/112052) (janeiro é zero, fevereiro é 1, etc).