# Como calcular o tempo de resposta de uma aplicação Node?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Qual a melhora forma de calcular o tempo de resposta de uma aplicação em `Node.js` ?

Sem muita delonga apenas a requisição sendo feita externa e um método que retorna o tempo através do `Date.now()`

Exemplo:

Aplicação Web:

```
function calcular() {
    var dataRequest = Date.now();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://rotaqueretornatempo/tempo,
        contentType: 'application/json',
        method: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            let tempo = Math.floor((data.resposta - dataRequest) / 1000)
            $("#demo").text(`Método: ${dataRequest} | Server: ${data.resposta}`)
        }
    });
}
```

Aplicação Node:

```
function applicationStatus(request: Request, response: Response){
  try {
    var dataResponse = Date.now();
    return response.json({resposta: dataResponse }) 
    
  } catch (error) {
    return response.json({resposta: error})
  }

}

routes.get('/tempo', applicationStatus);
```

> Como retorno: Método: 1605634553413 | Server: 1605635103030

Porém quando eu faço a subtração dos valores e faço a conversão pra segundos me da um retorno aproximado de 550 segundos, sendo que não leva nem 1 segundo pra ter a resposta.

Comment: Essa diferença de valores não seria por causa da sincronia do servidor e do browser do usuario? Porque voce esta usando o `Date.now()` de cada ambiente e, então, provavelmente eles não estão sincronizados. Não tenho certeza se pode ser isso. To deduzindo porque voce colocou uma url que não é local (localhost), então é um servidor remoto

Comment: Era exatamente isso o problema. O servidor está 10 minutos na frente da hora da aplicação. Valeu

Comment: Olá  Igor Carreiro, a timezone do servidor é diferente da timezone local (navegador). O Brasil usa -3 horas na maioria dos estados (o que depende do horário de verão), já o servidor geralmente usa a "zona zero" (UTC): https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/417492/3635

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quando você utiliza o método para pegar o horário atual no frontend, o horário retornado será o que o navegador estiver configurado. Quando você utilize esse mesmo método, só que no node.js, então será retornado o horário do servidor. Repare que se o horário do servidor for poucos milissegundos diferente do horário do usuário, então a medição do tempo será mal feita. A minha sugestão é utilizar algum software como o Postman, pois ele retorna quantos milissegundos exatos que a requisição gastou.