# Angular pegando um dia a menos na data

Tags: angular

Estou tentando corrigir a data em angular, o servidor retorna a data correta, mas meu campo de entrada é um dia a menos.

Pesquisei algumas soluções e tentei algo como "let isoDateInicio = new Date(myDate.inicio).toISOString();" a impressão no console mostra "2022-10-18T00:00:00.000Z", mas na minha entrada ainda diz "17-10-2022" como posso resolver isso?

aqui está um trecho do meu código onde tento corrigi-lo ao iniciar o componente.

```
findById(id: string) {
    this.service.findById(id).subscribe({
      next: (solicitacao) => {
        this.form.patchValue(solicitacao);
        let isoDateInicio = new Date(myDate.inicio).toISOString();
        this.form.get('inicio').setValue(isoDateInicio);
        console.log(this.form.get('inicio').value);
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Como resolver problema de acréscimo de 3 horas no atributo Date no Angular?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/416865/como-resolver-problema-de-acr%c3%a9scimo-de-3-horas-no-atributo-date-no-angular)

Answer (score 0):

O seu problema é referente ao TimeZone que é 3 horas de diferença com relação ao horário UTC (isoString usa o fuso horário sempre zero deslocamento UTC, conforme indicado pelo sufixo Z). Então o dia 18 de outubro as 00:00 da madrugada em Londres será 17 de outubro as 21:00 no Brasil.

Então a resolução do seu problema será você ajustar a data salva no Backend que esta sendo retornada para `"2022-10-18T03:00:00.000Z"`. ou usar uma gambiara com a biblioteca [`moment.js`](https://momentjs.com/) para somar 3 horas a hora recebida por você. Mas não indico a segunda opção fiz uma vez a muito tempo atrás e o que era pra ser algo simples só deu dor de cabeça.

Para mais informações consulte a documentação do [`toISOString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString)

Answer (score 0):

Deixa eu adivinhar. Seu back está usando MongoDB?

Não há nada de errado com a data. É que você está interpretando errado.

Você está recebendo a data num fuso horário com 3h de diferença.

Como a data se você não salva hora, marca a hora 00:00:00
Isso significa meia noite, se subtrair 3 horas, vai cair no outro dia.