# Somar 365 dias a uma data em um input type="date"

Tags: javascript, html, data

Estou com um problema tenho um input que digito uma data input formato date , queria somar o que foi digitado + 365 mas não consigo pelo `id` nem pela classe:

```js
function somaFerias(){  
  var Hoje = new Date();
  Hoje.setDate(Hoje.getDate(".campo") + 365);
  //string apenas de data em um formato determinado pelo browser
  var Today2 = Hoje.toLocaleDateString();

  alert(Today2)
}
```

```html
<p>Data de Admissão</p> 
    <input type="date"  class="campo" data-ls-module="charCounter" id="adm" maxlength="10" name="data" placeholder="01/01/1990" required> 


<input type="submit" value="Ferias" name="ferias" id="feria" onClick="somaFerias()">
```

Comment: Primeiro de tudo você tem que criar um botão para chama o método `somaFerias()` assim: `<button onclick="somaFerias()">Somar</button>`

Comment: ja criei desculpa nao colocar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Se você quer somar com a data que foi digitada, não faz sentido usar `new Date()`, que pega a data atual. Você tem que criar a data baseado no valor do `input`.

O detalhe é que um [`input type="date"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input/date#Value) retorna a data no formato "yyyy-mm-dd" (que é formato definido pela [norma ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)), e uma data criada com esta string [considera que o horário é meia-noite em UTC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse#Date_Time_String_Format) (*visualmente* no browser, a data pode estar em outro formato, mas internamente, quando você pega o `value` do `input`, o resultado estará como "yyyy-mm-dd").

Só que [`toLocaleDateString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString) pegará a data no fuso horário do browser, que não necessariamente é UTC, e pode dar diferença no resultado (por exemplo, no Horário de Brasília, estamos 3 horas atrás de UTC, então `toLocaleDateString()` mostrará "um dia a menos" do que foi digitado).

Outro detalhe é que por *default* é considerado o *locale* (configurações de idioma) do browser, então o formato usado por `toLocaleDateString` poderá ser diferente dependendo do ambiente onde o código roda. Se quiser sempre o mesmo formato, especifique um *locale* nos parâmetros (no exemplo abaixo usei `pt-BR`, que corresponde ao português usado no Brasil). E para evitar o problema de conversão de fuso-horário, indique que você quer que a data esteja em UTC:

```js
function somaFerias() {
    var data = new Date(document.getElementById('adm').value);
    data.setDate(data.getDate() + 365);
    //string apenas de data em um formato determinado pelo browser
    var dataFormatada = data.toLocaleDateString('pt-BR', {timeZone: 'UTC'});

    alert(dataFormatada);
}
```

```html
<p>Data de Admissão</p> 
<input type="date" class="campo" data-ls-module="charCounter" id="adm" maxlength="10" name="data" placeholder="01/01/1990" required> 
<input type="submit" value="Ferias" name="ferias" id="feria" onClick="somaFerias()">
```

Repare também que [`getDate()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDate) não recebe nenhum parâmetro.

---

Vale lembrar que somar 365 dias nem sempre resultará no mesmo dia e mês do ano seguinte, por causa dos anos bissextos. Neste caso, usar [`setFullYear`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setFullYear) seria mais adequado, veja a diferença neste exemplo:

```js
let d = new Date(2020, 0, 1); // 1 de janeiro de 2020
console.log(d);
// somar 1 ano
d.setFullYear(d.getFullYear() + 1);
console.log(d); // 1 de janeiro de 2021

//-----------------------------------------------------
d = new Date(2020, 0, 1); // 1 de janeiro de 2020
// somar 365 dias
d.setDate(d.getDate() + 365);
console.log(d); // 31 de dezembro de 2020
```

No exemplo acima, vale lembrar que o mês é zero porque em JavaScript [janeiro é zero, fevereiro é 1, etc](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/405994/112052) (mas só quando usamos os valores numéricos, pois quando usamos strings como `'2020-01-01'`, aí o mês deve ter o valor correto).

E a abordagem acima ainda terá um *corner case* que é quando somamos 1 ano a 29 de fevereiro:

```js
let d = new Date(2020, 1, 29); // 29 de fevereiro de 2020
console.log(d);
// somar 1 ano
d.setFullYear(d.getFullYear() + 1);
console.log(d); // 1 de março de 2021
```

O resultado é 1 de março. Pois é, [aritmética de datas é um negócio complicado](https://hkotsubo.github.io/blog/2019-04-09/nao-reinvente-a-roda-2-como-somar-meses-e-anos-a-uma-data)...

Comment: se tivesse como dar um milãho de likes eu daria valeu

Comment: @nikolaslutgens Se a resposta resolveu o seu problema, vc pode aceitá-la, [**veja aqui**](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1078/112052) como e porque fazê-lo. Não é obrigatório, mas é uma boa prática do site, para indicar a futuros visitantes que aquilo resolveu o problema. Não esqueça que [**vc também pode votar**](/help/privileges/vote-up) na resposta, caso tenha achado útil.

Comment: Eu não faço a menor ideia do porque o donvote, eu deixei um up vote. Eu queria perguntar o seguinte sobre anos bissextos, essa abordagem de somar 365 indiscriminadamente não daria problemas. Eu estou perguntando poque escrevi uma resposta usando o getFullYear() e setFullYear() pensando nos anos bissextos. Mas ai surgiu o negativo um pouco antes deu publicar minha resposta, então a abortei e preferi lhe perguntar ao invés de causar um mal entendido.

Comment: @AugustoVasques A pergunta diz claramente que quer somar 365 dias. Se a ideia é somar 1 ano, aí `setFullYear` é mais adequado porque se não me engano já faz esses ajustes levando em conta anos bissextos. E de qualquer forma, removeram o downvote :-)

Comment: Verdade eu ignorei o fato da pergunta especificar 365 dias e presumi o período de 1 anos.

Comment: @AugustoVasques Bom, de qualquer forma, adicionei um exemplo com `setFullYear` explicando a diferença. Obrigado pelo comentário!

Comment: @AugustoVasques Vale lembrar que nenhuma das abordagens é livre de *corner cases* e casos "estranhos". Por exemplo, 29 de fevereiro de 2020 + 1 ano é igual a que? Em algumas API's ou outras linguagens, o resultado é 28/02/2021, no JavaScript é 01/03/2021 (também adicionei esse exemplo na resposta). Esse cálculo nunca é tão simples quanto a gente gostaria...

Comment: @nikolaslutgens, isso setFullYear() só trabalha com tempo em anos.

Comment: @AugustoVasques posso fazer outra pergunta aqui ou abro outra pergunta? eu queria saber como jogo o valor dessa function em um outro  input  ao clicar no meu botao

Comment: @nikolaslutgens Se for algo simples como estou pensando, seria apenas `input.value = valor`. Se for mais complicado que isso, aí é o caso de fazer outra pergunta. Se bem que eu sugiro que faça uma busca no site antes, pois já deve ter várias perguntas sobre como colocar um valor em outro `input` :-)