# Ao tentar criar data 31 de outubro, resultado é 1 de dezembro

Tags: javascript, html, data, google-charts

Hoje fui visualizar um gráfico que tenho e percebi que ele estava todo bagunçado mas não entendi o porque. Olhei, revisei, retestei e nada de voltar ao normal. Estou supondo que seja um problema de conversão da data e hora do google chart...

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

  function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Data', 'Sales', 'Expenses'],
      [new Date(2020, 10, 30, 10, 36), 1000, 400],
      [new Date(2020, 10, 30, 12, 36), 1170, 460],
      [new Date(2020, 10, 30, 14, 36), 660, 1120],
      [new Date(2020, 10, 31, 16, 36), 1030, 540]
    ]);

    var options = {
      title: 'Company Performance',
      hAxis: {title: 'Year',  titleTextStyle: {color: '#333'}},
      vAxis: {minValue: 0}
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="chart_div" style="width: 100%; height: 500px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Estou me baseando por esse exemplo básico. As datas do dia 31/10/2020 acaba sendo convertida para 01/12/2020.

[image]

Será que estou deixando passar alguma coisa despercebida ou será algum problema de conversão no google chart?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isso acontece porque em um [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) os meses [são indexados em zero](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/405998/112052) (janeiro é zero, fevereiro é 1, etc).

E como você está passando o valor do mês igual a  10, então  na verdade está criando datas em novembro. Só que o construtor também faz alguns ajustes dependendo do caso. Por exemplo, como novembro tem 30 dias, ao tentar criar a data 31 de novembro, ele ajusta automaticamente para 1 de dezembro.

Então basta ajustar o valor do mês. Se quer datas em outubro, passe o valor 9:

```js
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

  function drawChart() {
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
  ['Data', 'Sales', 'Expenses'],
  [new Date(2020, 9, 30, 10, 36), 1000, 400],
  [new Date(2020, 9, 30, 12, 36), 1170, 460],
  [new Date(2020, 9, 30, 14, 36), 660, 1120],
  [new Date(2020, 9, 31, 16, 36), 1030, 540]
]);

var options = {
  title: 'Company Performance',
  hAxis: {title: 'Year',  titleTextStyle: {color: '#333'}},
  vAxis: {minValue: 0}
};

var chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
chart.draw(data, options);
  }
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="chart_div" style="width: 100%; height: 500px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Caramba, já tem uns dias que estou montando o gráfico e isso me passou completamente despercebido, ainda mais que o estou alimentando somente com dados do dia corrente e do nada tudo apareceu bagunçado e fiquei perdido. Vlw Pela ajuda.